# Launch Modelsim from Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, modelsim

I am trying to launch Modelsim simulator from cygwin.  I am able to compile using vcom in cygwin, but when I type ./vsim I see the following:

Reading C:/modeltech_pe_10.2a/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl

#10.2a

And then nothing happens.  I am able to launch vsim correctly via the windows command prompt.  Additionally, I am pretty sure my cygwin environment is set up correctly, because I can launch windows calculator from cygwin.  When I try to break the hung process (Ctrl + C) I  get the following error:

** Fatal: vish lost connection to vsim process.

** Fatal: Exiting VSIM license process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for those who might have this problem in the future.  Launch vsim with the -i switch.  This launches it in Interactive Mode.  This sets the display environment correctly within Cygwin.  It tells ModelSim to use the Windows display environment instead of the Linux display environment.

./vsim -i